# Is it possible to perform a regex pattern match in a SQL Server varchar(max) column and return the match?

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a log table that has some records that have this type of pattern:

```
.... "RefundId":"re_1ABasdf234234343434", "..."....
```

I want to extract and return the value of the `RefundId` in a column in a select statement, is this possible?

Comment: That looks like JSON.  Is it JSON?  If so you would be MUCH better served using a JSON parser over a regex.  And yes you could use regex to find it just -- I recommend an online regex tester to test your regex.

Comment: its not JSON...well its mixed JSON with text as it is a unstructured varchar where the developer just dumped log related data

Answer (score -1):

If there is only one Refund_ID for each row then you can use something like this:

```
--Create table
create table T1 (
    T1_id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    Log_Data varchar(max) null
)

--Insert test data
insert T1(Log_Data)
values('.... "RefundId":"re_1ABasdf234234343434", "..."....'),
(' "RefundId":"JHHJJHJHJHJJHJH", "..."....'),
(''),
(null)

--Get some results
select  *, left(substring(Log_Data, patindex('%"RefundId":"%', Log_Data)+12, 20000000), patindex('%"%', substring(Log_Data, patindex('%"RefundId":"%', Log_Data)+12, 20000000)) + case when patindex('%"%', substring(Log_Data, patindex('%"RefundId":"%', Log_Data)+12, 20000000)) > 0 then -1 else 0 end ) Refund_ID
from    T1
```

If there are multiple Refund_IDs for each value then you will have to find a different method.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the keyword `LIKE`

```
SELECT RefundId
FROM MyTable
WHERE RefundId LIKE 'some pattern'
```

Comment: Raga -- LIKE is not regex -- so there is not regex pattern that would work here.